# Static code analysis tool for C#

Tags: gratis, c#, code-analysis

I'm looking for a tool to support static code analysis for C#.

My requirements:

- run on Mono/Linux
- free (at least for open-source projects)
- integration with MonoDevelop is a plus, but not a requirement
- I'd love to have a class diagram for the whole solution
- having a CLI interface would be nice as well.

I know ReSharper/FxCop, on Linux we have NRefactory, but I'd like to see something more advanced/precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Refactoring Essentials](https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials/) for Visual Studio and other IDEs is an open source tool that has features which include refactorings for C# and analyzers and code fixes for C#.

---

Refactoring Essentials comes in the following flavors:

- VSIX: built for Visual Studio - supports analyzers and refactorings
- Nuget: packaged for build servers / IDEs that support analyzers via Nuget packages
- RefactoringEssentials assembly: usable in any IDE (-like environment), base assembly with all features

The latter means it is X-platform and not tied to Windows / Visual Studio. <sup>[source](https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for a hint. Shame it's not very active anymore. I'll mark your answer as a solution, as I don't think there will be much more traffic in this question anymore ;-)